# Detect when touch event is over in Hammer.js and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

In Hammer.js 2.02, how do you detect when a press gesture has ended?

I have a 'press' recognizer on an element with a time of 1 which prints a message as soon as the press event starts. But how do I check when the user has lifted their finger? Right now I'm using the 'pressup' recognizer which nearly works, except that it only triggers if the user has held their finger down for >500ms. How can I check when shorter presses end?

```
var pressOptions = {
    event: 'press',
    pointer: 1,
    threshold: 5,
    time: 1
};

var trackpadRight = $('#trackpad-right').hammer();
trackpadRight.data("hammer").get('press').set(pressOptions);

trackpadRight.bind('press', function(ev) {
    console.log("PRESSS DOWN");
});

trackpadRight.bind('pressup', function(ev) {
    console.log("PRESS UP");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, I thought you need to detect the touch release. If yes then you can use the default "touchend" event by directly bind to the element, like below:

```
$('#trackpad-right').bind('touchend', function(ev) {
    console.log("PRESS UP");
});
```

Comment: yes, first bind with hammerjs "press" with {time: 1} propertie, then jquery bind touchend and mouseup for stop

Answer (score 4):

Just use Hammer without jQuery.

```
var pressOptions = {
    // event: 'press', //no need to pass defaults
    // pointer: 1,
    // threshold: 5,
    time: 1
};

var trackpadRightTouch = new Hammer(document.getElementById('trackpad-right'));
trackpadRightTouch.get('press').set(pressOptions);

trackpadRightTouch.on('press', function(ev) {
    console.log("PRESSS DOWN");
});

trackpadRightTouch.on('pressup', function(ev) {
    console.log("PRESS UP");
});
```

this should work.

Comment: Actually, pressup does not fire if you you drag your finger a bit before releasing (hammver v2.0.4).

Comment: That's what the threshold value is for. You can change it to handle.

Comment: FWIW the pressup doesn't listen to the `time` thing in my experience. It sets it just fine for the regular `press` event.